# executing a html button's tasks through a local java application

Tags: java, html

The situation is: a server runs an asp page which displays a list of items with two buttons in the same row (delete and submit the item).

I want to build a local java application that can:

1. delete all elements from that list and
2. submit all elements at once when executed

(just a practice exercise).

1. the deletion works like calling the myserver.com/somescript.asp
   and handing over the ID of the element and the action_to_perform='delete' with post method so basically just querying a URL.

In my Java app I read the html output from the server converted it to a HTML DOM
document with a library and then extracted all the IDs by navigating to the children by using the functionality JSOUP provides.
Then I called all the URLs with the correct parameters and the deletion just works fine.

The actual problem comes with

2. that button is not just a href like in the deletion but it's calling some scripts in the onClick attribute I don't have access to.

My question is: How can I get my java app to execute that button's onClick=myscript.some_function()?

If you need some source code I got from the firefox developer inspector
just let me know.

I'm not that familiar with asp, JavaScript and such stuff so please be kind.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Do you mean Java or JavaScript? They are VERY different technologies.

Comment: Yes I implemented my programm in Java with Netbeans and Idk much about JavaScript.